# How to print in duplex mode with smbclient?

Tags: printing, smb

Because I don't want to give any information about a corporate printer to CUPS, because I suspect it trying to access it even when I'm not on the corporate network, I use the following "script" to print documents on a corporate printer managed by a Windows print server:

```
smbclient "//printserv.acme.corp/BUILDING0PRINTER1" "password" -c "print /tmp/my.pdf" -U "username" -W "Domain"
```

The printer is some HP MFP and can very well print duplex. My command, however, does not print duplex.

My question is: How to print a PDF in duplex mode (such that both sides of the paper sheet are used, aka flip on long edge)?

I don't mind extending my "script" by prepending some weird PCL or Postscript commands, but I don't want CUPS to be searching for the printer (and potentially send my password into the ether).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that `pdftops` provides a `-duplex` switch.
So I scripted the following:

`pdftops -paper A4 -duplex  "$1" "${1}.ps"
smbclient "//printserv.acme.corp/BUILDING0PRINTER1" "password" -c "print \"${1}.ps\"" -U "username" -W "Domain"`

Comment: How does one pass the `/tmp/my.pdf` into this script?

Comment: The "$1" is the first argument into the script. So if you pass it the filepath of the pdf you want to print, it will print that.
Answer: you can put it in a script named `some_printing_script.sh` like:
`#!/bin/bash `(start a new line here)
`pdftops .. `(start a new line here)
`smbclient .. `(start a new line here)
, make it runnable with: `chmod +x some_printing_script.sh` and then run it with:`./some_printing_script.sh /tmp/my.pdf`.